# Conditions on $f$ and $g$ if $(g\circ f)^{-1}$ exists

Tags: functions, inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition

Consider functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ $(A,B,C\subseteq R)$ such that $(g\circ f)^{-1}$ exists, then :

(1) $f$ is onto and $g$ is one-one

(2) $f$ is one-one and $g$ is onto

(3) $f$ and $g$ are both one-one

(4) $f$ and $g$ are both onto

One of the above options is supposed to be correct but I think for inverse to exist we must have bijection so both (3) and (4) should be correct. I am little confused

Comment: The correct answer is $(2)$.

Comment: Maverick, look at my answer. Do you manage to prove the two claims I wrote ? If you want, I will write the proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to prove that

$g\circ f\;$ is one-one $\implies f\;$ is one-one.

$g\circ f\;$ is onto $\implies g\;$ is onto.

Consequently,

since $\;\left(g\circ f\right)^{-1}$ exists, then $\;g\circ f\;$ is one-one and onto, hence $\;f\;$ is one-one and $\;g\;$ is onto.

So the correct answer is $(2)$.

---

**Addendum .**

**Claim 1 :**$\quad g\circ f\;$ is one-one $\implies f\;$ is one-one.

*Proof :* $\;$ Let $\;a_1\;$ and $\;a_2\;$ be two elements of the set $\;A\;.$

$f(a_1)=f(a_2)\;$ implies that $\;(g\circ f)(a_1)=(g\circ f)(a_2)\;$ and, since $\;g\circ f\;$ is one-one, we get that $\;a_1=a_2\;.$

So we have proved that $f(a_1)=f(a_2)\;$ implies $\;a_1=a_2\;,\;$ consequently $\;f\;$ is one-one.

**Claim 2 :**$\quad g\circ f\;$ is onto $\implies g\;$ is onto.

*Proof :* $\;$ Since $\;g\circ f\;$ is onto, it follows that

for any $\;c\in C\;$ there exists $\;a\in A\;$ such that $\;(g\circ f)(a)=c\;,$

consequently,

for any $\;c\in C\;$ there exists $\;b=f(a)\in B\;$ such that $\;g(b)=(g\circ f)(a)=c\;,$

hence $\;g\;$ is onto.

Comment: What if you take $A=B=C=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=g(x)=e^x$?

Comment: @MatthewPilling, if $A=B=C=\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=g(x)=e^x$, then $(g\circ f)(x)=e^{e^x}$ is one-one but it is not onto, so there does not exist $(g\circ f)^{-1}$. Moreover, since $(g\circ f)$ is one-one, then $\;f\;$ is one-one too.

Comment: In my example $(g\circ f)^{-1}(x)$ does exist. It's equal to $\ln(\ln(x))$. The problem doesn't indicate that the domain of $(g\circ f)^{-1}$ is all of $C$. In general, the domain of $(g\circ f)^{-1}$ if it exists is equal to $(g\circ f)(A)$ which is a subset of $C$. In my example the domain of $(g\circ f)^{-1}$ is $ (1,\infty)$. You should note that $(g\circ f)^{-1}$ exists but $g$ is not surjective.

Comment: $(g\circ f)^{-1}$ exists if $\;C=(1,+\infty)$. In this case, $\;f\;$ is one-one and $\;g\;$ is onto. See the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Definitions

Comment: Actually, $\;\ln\big(\ln(x)\big):(1,+\infty)\to\mathbb R\;$ is the inverse function of $\;g\circ f:\mathbb R\to(1,+\infty)\;$, whereas the function $\;g\circ f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\;$ is not invertible because it is only one-one but not onto.

Comment: What you're saying is like claiming the inverse of $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=e^x$ doesn't exist since $\mathbb{R}\neq (0,\infty)$. The inverse *does* exists, it's just that its domain is not the entire codomain of $f$. In general, if $f:A\rightarrow B$ is injective, then $f^{-1}:f(A)\rightarrow B$ exists and satisfies $f^{-1}\circ f\equiv \text{id}_{A}$.

Comment: There exists the inverse of the function $\;f:\mathbb R\to(0,+\infty)\;$ defined by $\;f(x)=e^x\;$ and the inverse function is $\ln x:(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R\;.$

Comment: @MatthewPilling, if your definition of invertible function were correct, the correct answer of the OP’s question would be that $\;f\;$ is one-one and no condition for $\;g\;$ but there is no such answer. So, it is obvious that in the exercise of the OP a function is invertible if it is one-one and onto.

Comment: Also, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Definitions In this link you can find the following sentence “ To be invertible, a function must be both an injection and a surjection. Such functions are called bijections. ”

Answer (score 3):

Think of the following simple set functions:

$$\{1,2\} \to \{1,2,3\} \to \{1,2\},$$
where the first one sends $1$ to $1$ and $2$ to $2$, and the second one sends $1$ to $1$, $2$ to $2$ and $3$ to $1$.
The composition is the identity and thus clearly invertible. The functions, though, are not invertible.

You should be able to derive the answer you are looking for from this example.

Comment: The correct answer is $(2)$.